# How to know the UI is responsive or not in react native

Tags: android, react-native

As mobile development, there is any suggest to test that UI we build is responsive or not in another device?

I have using react native responsive screen, I tired to change the number in widthPercentageToDP. In my emulator is fine but sometime when app in testing another device with QA team, the problem comes

Comment: Update emulator resolution to small or large and launch simulator again and for iOS launch it in specific simulator i.e for smaller device i use iPhone SE 2nd generation simulator.

Comment: can we just using one emulator and than change the resolution or is there emulator except android emulator that can change resolution when we just download one emulator?

Comment: or maybe is there away or formula to get number that we using in widthPercentageToDP is responsive to another device

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flex for normal UI and window formula for different screens.